# Problem with rendering user's data from Firebase/Firestore using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm fetching the user's data by the user's UID from Firestore using ReactJS into a table. First, it shows all the data from all the documents of all the users in the table, only after I refresh the page, I can see only the logged-in user data. In addition, if I change something in the code, in a specific file, the table will show again all the documents of all the users until I refresh the page again. And if I'm trying to add a value to the table, it will show all the data and the logged-in user data will be duplicated in the table. After I refresh the page again, it will show only 1 user data by UID - as I want, but only after page refresh.

I know that I have a problem with fetching data or with the useState initialization in this situation.

**Screenshot before the page refresh:**

[image]

**after page refresh (expected result):**

[image]

```
export default function Nutrition() {
// use state
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
        const dbRef = collection(db, "data");
        let foods = []
        if (user) {
            const uid = user.uid
            const snapshot = await getDoc(doc(db, "data", uid));
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                onSnapshot(dbRef, (querySnapshot) => {
                    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                        const { value, quantity } = doc.data()
                        for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
                            foods.push({ value: value[i], quantity: quantity[i] })
                        }
                    });
                    setData(foods)
                })
            } else {
                console.log("User doc missing")
            }
        } else {
            console.log("User not logged in")
            setData([])
        }
    })
}, [])

return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <div className='container mt-3'>
            {/* table */}
            <table className='table table-hover'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Food</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {data.map((row, index) => {
                        // console.log(data[row])
                        return (
                            <tr key={row.id}>
                                <td>{index + 1}</td>
                                <td>{row.value}</td>
                                <td>{row.quantity}</td>
                            </tr>
                        )
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <button className='btn btn-dark mt-3'>Reset table</button>
        </div>
    </React.Fragment>
)
```

}

Comment: Where in your code are you fetching the `exercises` collection you mention in one of the screenshot. Also note that your listener (`onSnapshot()`) is set on the entire `data` collection.

Comment: I'm sorry, look at this as "data" collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following code

```
            onSnapshot(dbRef, (querySnapshot) => {
                querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                    const { value, quantity } = doc.data()
                    for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
                        foods.push({ value: value[i], quantity: quantity[i] })
                    }
                });
                setData(foods)
            })
```

you actually set a real-time listener on the **entire** `data` collection since `const dbRef = collection(db, "data");`.

> I can see only the logged-in user data

If I'm not mistaking, from your code I don't see where you restrict the data pushed to the `foods` array to the data corresponding to the logged-in user. So it is not clear to me how you can "see only the logged-in user data".

The only thing you do which is linked to a user is fetching the **document** of the `data` collection with an ID corresponding to the logged-in user ID and checking if it exists or not. And if it exists you push the **entire** `data` collection data to the `foods` array (so the data displaying process on your front-end is not linked to the logged-in user data, apart from checking if the user's doc exists or not).

---

So if I correctly understand your goal (displaying the lines of the `value` and `quantity` arrays from the user's document in the `data` collection) the following should do the trick:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
      let foods = [];
      if (user) {
        const uid = user.uid;
        const snapshot = await getDoc(doc(db, 'data', uid));
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
          const { value, quantity } = snapshot.data();
          for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            foods.push({ value: value[i], quantity: quantity[i] });
          }
          setData(foods);
        } else {
          console.log('User doc missing');
        }
      } else {
        console.log('User not logged in');
        setData([]);
      }
    });
  }, []);
```